# How do open parent product, via child SKU in URL

Tags: magento, magento2.2

I want to open a parent product page when someone searches or use child / configurable product in SKU.
I am using Magento ver. 2.2.8

This is the parent product URL, which opens 
http://plego.xyz/lr3322.html

This is child/configurable product, which gives 404 Not Found
http://plego.xyz/lr3322mr2.html

Comment: In configuration product,child product visibility hidden that's why it returns 404. When I try to open this http://plego.xyz/lr3322mr2.html url it redirects to http://plego.xyz/lr3322.html#151=163

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your child product `visibility` attribute as `not visible individually` it will not appear in the search result.

However, if you hit the child product URL will still be shown as 404.

In real-life scenarios, the customer will not type direct URL they will search the product from the search bar itself.